# NSThread Error

Tags: iphone

I have two uiviewcontrollers. I am using NSThread in first viewcontroller and its works perfect.. Some times the thread was running in the firstviewcontroller, that time i Want to go Secondviewcontroller.This action stops my thread of firstviewcontrollr..

How could i fix this... Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you could clarify the question, because it's hard to understand exactly what you want to do and what the problem is. In general, UI code should **always** run in the main thread. That is clearly stated in the Cocoa documentation, and you will not succeed in having several threads trying to control the UI.

If you want to run code in other threads and have them influence the UI, you need to implement mechanisms to communicate information to the main thread. One method that comes in handy is NSObject's

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;
```

If you want to use notifications, you must dispatch them on the main thread also. It is easy to get confusing bugs if you don't stick to this principle (although things might seems to work at first).